# Including native c++ .so library in IntelliJ using JNI under Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, java-native-interface

I'm building a shared library which will be called from Java IntelliJ using JNI under Ubuntu 14.04 x64.
When calling my .so file using `System.loadLibrary("libtestJniLib")` in Intellij I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
libtestJniLib in java.library.path
```

The Intellij configurations determine the path to library:

```
1) Run->Edit Configurations->VM options: -Djava.library.path=/home/username/Libs
2) In "Project structure -> Libraries ->Native library locations"
```

I added the same path: `/home/username/Libs`

When testing it using method mentioned below I have a correct path.

```
String javaLibPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
```

IntelliJ's started under root.

Comment: What's the full name of your library, including the extension?

Comment: The library name is libtestJniLib.so

Answer (score 2):

When you're loading a shared library using [`System.LoadLibrary()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String%29), the following applies:

> Loads the system library specified by the libname argument. **The manner
>   in which a library name is mapped to the actual system library is
>   system dependent.**

The best description I can find for that mapping is [here](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/native1.1/stepbystep/_library.html):

> Each Java runtime environment provides a platform-dependent mechanism
>   for mapping between the actual file name of a shared library and the
>   name string that you pass as an argument to the System.loadLibrary
>   method.
>
> Solaris:
>
> The shared library file name requires a "lib" prefix and a ".so"
>   extension. Do not include the "lib" prefix or the ".so" extension for
>   the argument that you pass to the `System.loadLibrary` method.
>
> Microsoft Windows:
>
> The shared library file name requires a ".dll" extension.
>   Do not include the ".dll" extension for the `System.loadLibrary` method
>   argument.

Comment: 2nd link is broken